# How can I detect if a browser supports the multipart/x-mixed-replace mime-type?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, mime-types, multipart-mixed-replace

I am using a feature in my site that needs to use the multipart/x-mixed-replace mime-type.

How can I detect if a browser supports the multipart/x-mixed-replace mime-type?

> **NOTE:**
>
> I am not looking for a browser detection but for a feature detection